# Append Data from 1 Table to Another with Image Column Across Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, query, insert, linked-server

MSSQL - I am trying to append data from Table 1 that doesn't exist in Table 2.  The tables have the same columns.  One of the columns is image format and is not 'comparable'.  Table 2 is across a linked server.  The primary key consists of 3 columns.

```
INSERT INTO Link.DB2.dbo.Table2
SELECT * FROM DB1.dbo.Table1 T1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM Link.DB2.dbo.Table2 T2
WHERE T1.Col1 = T2.Col1 and T1.Col2 = T2.Col2 and T1.Col3 = T2.Col3
```

I know this won't work but just trying to explain what I need to do.  I am unable to do a linked server from the destination database.

How would I format this type of statement?

Comment: "*I know this won't work...*" - Why?...are you receiving a specific error and if so what?

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).